# gparted (live usb) says my partition is mounted, but where?

Tags: linux, lvm, gparted

I'm attempting to grow `/dev/sda5`, which is an 'lvm2 pv' partition, but it's contained in `/dev/sda2`, which is an extended partition.

There is plenty of "unallocated" space immediately after `/dev/sda2`, since I've just cloned my previous disk to a larger one.

My plan is to resize the extended partition, and then resize the contained PV to match. Then I'll extend the VG and the filesystem.

So I've booted using a Linux Mint 17.1 USB stick and run gparted. It won't let me resize the extended partition, claiming that it's "Busy (At least one logical partition is mounted)".

However, running `mount` (or `cat /proc/mounts`) doesn't show anything other than the Live USB image mounted.

What's the problem?

Comment: **Why** do you want to extend a PV instaed of just adding a new one?

Comment: Because the free space is directly adjacent to the existing PV. Why wouldn't I want to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the partition contains an LVM2 volume group, it's treated as busy (even if it doesn't appear mounted). You need to deactivate the VG:

```
sudo vgscan      # to discover the name of the volume group "mint-vg"
sudo vgchange -a n mint-vg
```

Then, in gparted, select `GParted` / `Refresh Devices`. This should remove the lock icon from the partitions.

*Aside: rather than a lock icon, my copy of gparted displays a telephone, which is ... confusing.*

At this point, you should be able to resize the extended partition, `/dev/sda2` as normal to use the unallocated space. Apply the change.

Then resize the 'lvm2 pv' partition, `/dev/sda5`. Apply the change.

Then resize the PV:

```
sudo pvresize /dev/sda5
```

Check the new size:

```
sudo pvdisplay /dev/sda5
```

Reactivate the volume group:

```
sudo vgchange -a y mint-vg
```

Then extend the logical volume into the new space:

```
sudo lvextend /dev/mint-vg/root /dev/sda5
```

I forgot to specify `-r` to resize the filesystem, so I have to do that as well...

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/mint-vg/root
sudo resize2fs /dev/mint-vg/root
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The last bit about resizing the file system was crucial to me.

Comment: Wow.  This answered my question exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The LVM2 Volume Group(s) on your PV are started. Logical Volumes on this VG(s) might also be started. Stop them with `lvchange -an` and `vgchange -an` (after making sure no filesystems from any VG/LV is mounted.)

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out shortly after I posted the question -- bringing up the Information window for the lvm partition in gparted shows "Status: mint-vg active". Could you take a look at my answer and maybe throw in some comments or edits, please?

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot. I also had to unmount swap partition first using `swapoff` - without this `vgchange -an` was not able to stop it.